# No column name was specified for column error

Tags: sql, xml

I am trying to remove trailing commas from a data which has been concatenated using XML path.

When I nest the XML Path query in the LEFT function query, I get all sorts of errors.

It gives me

> Incorrect syntax error nest ')'

pointing to the closing bracket before [tb].

When I use alias for the inner query, it gives me

> no column was specified

This is my query

```
select 
    LEFT(tb.col1, LEN(tb.col1) - 2)
from 
    (select 
        col1 + ', '
     from 
        tabSample 
     where 
        tabId = XXXX
     For XMl Path('') ) [tb]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select STUFF((select  ', ' + col1 
              from tabSample 
              where tabId = XXXX
              For XMl Path(''),TYPE).
              value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'')
```

Add a comma in front of the value and then use `STUFF` function to remove the very 1st comma. The above example only deals with the leading comma issue.

You probably need to look at the whole query as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still get the 'No column name was specified error' :(

Comment: Paste your whole query that you have used. Here it is saying no Column was specified because you are using this XML query as an INNER Query and when you use this syntax your inner query must have a column name for each column returned from your query

Comment: Thanks. Adding columnName with table name worked. Thanks a lot